# different push/pull urls for git submodule

Tags: git, git-submodules, gitlab

I'm using the [git superproject pattern](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Git/Submodules_and_Superprojects) in a large project which is deployed by a Teamcity build agent which does not have a repository account, however the repository is set up to allow anonymous cloning. For this reason I have set up the submodules with their `http://` url rather than their git url. The issue with this is that the repository rejects http pushes:

```
Total 0 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0)
error: RPC failed; result=22, HTTP code = 401
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
```

So every time I update the submodules when switching branches, I have to do a `git remote add-url --push` to add the `git://` url.

Is there any way to set up the submodules in the superproject such that they already use the `http://` url for pulling and the `git://` url for pushing?

Comment: Maybe set the `pushURL` in `.git/submodules/<sub>/config`.

Answer (score 6):

The [LibreOffice project also uses submodules](https://wiki.documentfoundation.org/Development/Submodules) and includes:

> By default you submodules repository is in a state called 'detached HEAD' that means that the commit checked-out -- which is the one that the super-project (core) need -- is not associated with a local branch name.
>
> Don't forget to add a correct pushurl for the submodule you are working on or you will not be able to commit.

```
$ editor .git/modules/submodule/config
```

> And in the section `[remote "origin"]` add:

```
pushurl = ssh://logerrit/submodule
```

(similar to [soulseekah](https://stackoverflow.com/users/482864/soulseekah)'s [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16080415/different-push-pull-urls-for-git-submodule#comment22955624_16080415)) (in your case, use a `git://` address)

You can also do it through (within a submodule)

```
git config remote.origin.pushurl git://...
```

If you don't, as illulstrated in [this project](http://www.itk.org/Wiki/Git/Trouble), you would get a:

```
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
```

Comment: so once that is done, is there any way to push that config to the repository so that any new clones will get it?

Comment: @BiggAl no this is a *local* config, which wouldn't be pushed.

Comment: as a note to myself, vime search and replace can be done as `g:url=:s:^\(.\+\)url=http\(.\+\)/\(qa/.\+\)$:\1url=http\2/\3\r\1pushurl=git\2\:\3:` in .submodules or `g:url = :s:^\(.\+\)url = http\(.\+\)/\(qa/.\+\)$:\1url = http\2/\3\r\1pushurl = git\2\:\3:` in .git/config

Comment: I think this the best method to have a different push repo address, because the fetch url in .gitmodules need not change, and can be download by any other user who don't need do push operation.